# mvn spring-boot:run vs Run

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea, spring-boot, livereload

I'm testing spring-boot-devtools with livereload on intelliJ. 
I have simple SpringBootApplication that works fine.

When I start the app from maven command "mvn spring-boot:run" all works fine excepting that livereload server dont' start. No message on console appears and the chrome extensions show error that It's not possible to connect to livereload server.

If I start app with (right mousse button/Run Application.java), all works fine even livereload server. Message appears on console and browser is able to connect to livereload server.

**Starting app from right mousse button/Run Application.java**

Console message

```
2016-07-13 16:39:47.947  INFO 10440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-07-13 16:39:48.026  INFO 10440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2016-07-13 16:39:48.077  INFO 10440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-07-13 16:39:48.145  INFO 10440 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8090 (http)
```

**Starting app from mvn command "mvn spring-boot:run"**

Chorme extension message:

```
Could not connect to LiveReload server. Please make sure that a compatible LiveReload server is running. (We recommend guard-livereload, until LiveReload2 comes to your platform.)
```

Console message. *See that not show message LiveReload server is running on port....*

```
2016-07-13 16:38:56.749  INFO 6924 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-07-13 16:38:56.852  INFO 6924 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-07-13 16:38:56.898  INFO 6924 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8090 (http)
```

Why maven command don't start livereload server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to tell Maven to fork a separate JVM to run your application, rather than it running in the same JVM as Maven:

```
$ mvn spring-boot:run -Dfork=true
```